# ROR - Two Field Relations Of One Model [ORM]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Case:**
I have a model (" ride_request ")
in ride_request there are two fields ( pickup_location , dropoff_location )
both fields (pickup and dropoff) are instances of one model (*location*)

Here is my migrate

```
create_table :ride_requests do |t|
  t.integer :pickup_location
  t.integer :dropoff_location
```

**Question:**
How do I create a relation to location in the fields pickup/drop when normaly you would use location_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :class_name and :foreign_key to indicate the differences

```
Class RideRequest
  belongs_to :pickup, :class_name => "location", :foreign_key => "pickup_location"
  belongs_to :dropoff, :class_name => "location", :foreign_key => "dropoff_location"
```

Comment: Q: belongs_to looks right technically to make it work  but the thing is that there will only ever be one pickup and dropoff location for any one ride_request also the ride_request "has" a pickup/dropoff location and does not belong to the locations. So knowing that dues belongs_to still fit the bill?

Comment: @DigitalCake In my experience, the primary point to consider when stating the `belongs_to` is which table the foreign key should be on. As you are noting, occasionally it can bump up against your domain concepts/terms in some seemingly illogical ways, but if the database design is solid, I wouldn't worry too much about it. (If it really bothers you, you'll have to find a way to reframe the domain terms in a way that reads more logically.)